# how can I let the array list to be clickable?

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I am trying to handle this list to be clickable.
When I set an intent activity it doesn't work so how can I handle each element in this array list.
The error is when I press on any element in this array list it left me to the last intent I gave it.

```
package com.adnan.android.autofix;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.net.Inet4Address;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Array list content
        ArrayList<String> CarsBrand = new ArrayList<String>();
        CarsBrand.add("Alfa Romeo");
        CarsBrand.add("Audi");
        CarsBrand.add("BMW");
        CarsBrand.add("Brilliance");
        CarsBrand.add("BYD");
        CarsBrand.add("Changan");
        CarsBrand.add("Chery");
        CarsBrand.add("Chevorlet");
        CarsBrand.add("Chrysler");
        ArrayAdapter<String> CarsBrandAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, CarsBrand);

        GridView listView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.ListCarsBrands);

        listView.setAdapter(CarsBrandAdapter);

        // handling the array list
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent AlfaRomeoIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlfaRomeo.class);
                startActivity(AlfaRomeoIntent);

                Intent AudiIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.adnan.android.autofix.Audi.class);
                startActivity(AudiIntent);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: please add error log

Comment: an ArrayList is not a UI component, how do you imagine it being Clickable? You should also read up on naming conventions in Java, it would make your code a whole lot easier to follow/understand

Comment: You can't launch 2 activities on single button click. It will only open the last intent passed

Comment: Then what should I do?

Comment: what you want to do can you please elaborate?

Comment: create 2 buttons

Comment: @Bunny I am creating a cars app so there are a lot of models for each brand so I want to go to another by clicking on each element of this array list to show the each models of these brands

Comment: @waqasalm
yes it's compile

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can map your list items to their corresponding activity classes like this:

```
package com.adnan.android.autofix;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.net.Inet4Address;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements {
    HashMap<String, Class> intentMap ;
    ArrayList<String> CarsBrand;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Array list content
        CarsBrand = new ArrayList<String>();
        CarsBrand.add("Alfa Romeo");
        CarsBrand.add("Audi");
        CarsBrand.add("BMW");
        CarsBrand.add("Brilliance");
        CarsBrand.add("BYD");
        CarsBrand.add("Changan");
        CarsBrand.add("Chery");
        CarsBrand.add("Chevorlet");
        CarsBrand.add("Chrysler");
        ArrayAdapter<String> CarsBrandAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, CarsBrand);

        intentMap = new HashMap<String, Class>()
        {{
        put("Alfa Romeo", AlfaRomeo.class);
        put("Audi", Audi.class);
        // PUT ALL STRING-CLASS PAIRS LIKE THIS

        }};

        GridView listView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.ListCarsBrands);

        listView.setAdapter(CarsBrandAdapter);

        // handling the array list
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Class selectedIntentClass = intentMap.get(CarsBrand.get(position));
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, selectedIntentClass);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: I edited my answer, it had some typos. Try again please. I already tried and it worked for me.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/masqueNada/01cba62af84c2d5b55fb84b245dedce0 have a look at what i've tried

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try Like this :

```
package com.adnan.android.autofix;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.net.Inet4Address;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Array list content
        ArrayList<String> CarsBrand = new ArrayList<String>();
        CarsBrand.add("Alfa Romeo");
        CarsBrand.add("Audi");
        CarsBrand.add("BMW");
        CarsBrand.add("Brilliance");
        CarsBrand.add("BYD");
        CarsBrand.add("Changan");
        CarsBrand.add("Chery");
        CarsBrand.add("Chevorlet");
        CarsBrand.add("Chrysler");
        ArrayAdapter<String> CarsBrandAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, CarsBrand);

        GridView listView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.ListCarsBrands);

        listView.setAdapter(CarsBrandAdapter);

        // handling the array list
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                final String item = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                switch (item) {
                    case "Alfa Romeo":
                        Intent AlfaRomeoIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlfaRomeo.class);
                        startActivity(AlfaRomeoIntent);
                        break;
                    case "Audi":
                        Intent AudiIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.adnan.android.autofix.Audi.class);
                        startActivity(AudiIntent);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: change this `final String item = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position)` to this `String item = CarsBrand.get(position)` but you should declare your CarsBrand as a global field first

Comment: I have updated my code and now it's working fine. I have checked and get a correct response as well.